# Absence of Denarius implies the third scroll has already been opened in Revelation 6?

Tags: eschatology, revelation

The Revelation that Jesus Christ gave to his servant John describes a series of seven scrolls and seven trumpets that precede the end of the age. The scrolls are opened and in the first four, John is told by each of of the four living creatures to go and see and he sees riders on **differently colored horses**. The first horse is **white** which goes forth to conquer and conquering. The next horse is **red** and it's rider is commanded to take away **peace** from the world so that a world War may happen and cause many inhabitants of the earth to die. The third horse is **black** and the rider of this horse is commanded to cause **scarcity** on the earth such that a quart of wheat should cost a **denarius** and three quarts of barley should cost a denarius. Since this **currency** is no longer in use, is it safe to conclude that this event already happened?

In the modern context, the red horse causes an event similar to a nuclear warfare and then after this **scarcity** which brings about **inflation** but the currency described in this verse aged away with the Roman Empire, so has this event already happened?

Comment: The point is "will be expensive". Any currency will do.

Comment: @StephenDisraeli, but a quart of wheat for a single dollar is very cheap according to modern standards?

Comment: These things are clearly symbolic. Such measures and terms do not last long on the earth, The vision is given that concepts may be grasped. The technicalities are representative, not actual.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to understand the Revelation in a chronological time-line as you suggest gets nobody anywhere. Right from the giving of the visions to John until Christ suddenly returns, the book of the Revelation is depicting a gradual build-up of those events. Note - there is one scroll with seven seals on it. The risen Christ opens the seals. **All of the first four opened seals on that scroll can be seen to have happened from Christ's ascension onward.** The four symbolic 'horses' (Rev. 6:1-14) are still galloping around the globe, and won't stop until the rider on the white horse switches from holding a bow without any arrows, to having a double edged sword protruding from his mouth (Rev. 19:11-16).

Viewing this rider on the white horse as crowned (a King) and holding a bow but without any arrows mentioned, indicates Christ the King going forth to conquer those who are to be set free and brought into his kingdom. That started with his incarnation. No force is used on them. Those he conquers are won to him, being drawn with cords of love. But in Rev. 19:11-16 this King then comes in judgment against all his enemies and this dreadful sword has replaced the harmless bow without arrows. That is still future. Until then, he is winning willing subjects.

Compare that with the rider on the red horse, the second opened seal on that scroll. He takes peace away from the Earth (war); killing with a symbolic great sword. There certainly have always been wars on Earth, but when Jesus came he warned of future wars and rumours of wars (even a rumour of a war takes peace away.) But wars would then be a ***beginning*** of pangs of sorrows (Mt. 24:6-8) and they truly have escalated and become global. Only recently has the potential for destroying all life on Earth through a nuclear war struck terror into humanity. Wars are increasing and becoming more deadly.

That is an example of how the opened seals on that scroll build up in intensity over the centuries. You ask specifically about the third seal: does absence of the denarius indicate that the third seal has been opened? Well, ***there have always been famines, but what is to happen once Christ ascends?*** A Christian prophet, Agabus, is recorded in the Bible as foretelling a coming famine - Acts 11:28. **Famines are to continue throughout the centuries until Christ returns.** As Earth's billions increase, and droughts, wild-fires and suchlike also increase, famines increase. They continue to this day globally, so naming a particular coin is not the point. Famines just keep on getting worse from his ascension until he returns.

The depiction of one seal after another being broken open gives structure to the visions, but the whole book of the ***Revelation keeps repeating the events, seven times, building up the intensity of global events, clarifying the picture, adding principles upon earlier points in the previous sections.*** Repetition for emphasis. Building up to get a higher and higher view until we are no longer land-locked but getting the 'view' from heaven, looking down on the world just before Christ returns.

**The matter of the third opened seal is as on-going as all the other seals.** They are opened once the Lamb, in the midst of heaven's throne takes the scroll from the Father's hand and opens all seven seals. ***They start to be fulfilled from Christ's ascension onward, continually throughout the centuries, with increasing intensity, until Christ suddenly descends to judge the world.***

The opening of the seals is not a time-line to enable us to anticipate when exactly Christ will return. They have already been opened, though "the last seven plagues" clearly indicate previous sets of seven plagues; it's just that the last seven are the most severe there have ever been. Try looking at the book of the Revelation differently - not as a time-line, but as God's way of preparing Christians in every century for the tribulations and testing they will have to experience. Knowing that God is sovereignly in control no matter that world conditions just keep getting worse, keeps our faith strong. Knowing God has predicted just what will happen, and that he is the one causing the seals to be opened and pouring out the plagues on an increasingly godless world assures us that his timing is perfect. We do not need to know when Christ will return. We just need to be prepared to maintain faith while we live, whether he comes for us, or whether we die before then. That is the purpose of the book of the Revelation: to tell the saints what is to come so that we will not fall for the great deception the evil one perpetrates. This book takes over 600 pages to go into all of that: *The Revelation of Jesus Christ* by John Metcalfe, http://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm

Comment: Are the riders of these horses the same person?

Comment: @DongLi How could the glorified Christ be the same as the three others? He is over all others. There is none like unto him. He is the only-begotten of the Father. He rides forth to conquer as King of God's Kingdom then will ride forth to destroy all enemies of the Kingdom at his return. The symbolism of the three others clearly depicts, not persons, but spiritual powers under the authority of the one sending them forth. They are not called 'persons', or 'angels' in the vision. That's significant. Neither are the 'horses' literal horses.

Comment: They could be literal horses because horses took Elijah directly from the physical world to the dwelling of God in heaven. Also Christ will come and make war on the beast and his kingdom from a horse and issuing a sharp sword from his mouth. There are horses and chariots in heaven but well answered.

Comment: It is amazing how the struggle between good and evil starts right in front of God's throne and ends on earth with God's right hand man making war right on top of a white horse and the word from his mouth is a sword. Glory to God in the highest.

Comment: @Dong Li  I won't comment on your view about literal horses and a literal sword protrouding from Christ's mouth. This is just to say that I've learned that Christ is not "God's right-hand-man", but God's right hand (symbolically speaking!)

Comment: The sword from his mouth is not literal but the horse is literal lol. Okay you win there is no way the sword is literal while the horses aren't. Good Point. Revelation is symbology but we may not understand  these prophecies just like the Jewish elders failed to decipher the identity of the Messiah but the wise men who were not even Jewish knew.

Comment: Here (and throughout Revelation) John is describing what he sees. So we should think of these passages as word pictures, and the question becomes: what is the overall picture, and what does it mean? Focussing on the exact meaning of every single brush stroke separately risks missing the whole point of the picture.